# Why is XPath returning html for tags that aren't descendants of the target tag?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape [this URL](https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/russia/itf-m15-kazan-3-men/minin-matvey-ibragimov-daniel-SzECstVt/) with Scrapy as follows:

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='event-status']").get()
```

However, it seems to be returning the html for tags that aren't descendants of the target tag.

I've tried loading the webpage into [this XPath tester](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester) and running the XPath but no results are returned which is even more strange.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is the exact value want? `0:2`?

Comment: Hi. I just all the text from that tag but I wasn't sure on what the XPath was so I was just trying to start with getting the tag and working from there

Comment: Can you include a small sample of the html? Also what makes the tag the “target”? You’re using ‘//‘, and it looks like from the root, so you should expect everything (that matches your id predicate.

Comment: @ZachYoung - hey. I included the link in the question?

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I’m on a mobile device and cannot navigate to the link and view the source. You need to show us the minimum information that fully reproduces the problem. Include a sample of the HTML, not the full thing, that gives you the undesired result.

Comment: Hey @ZachYoung - when I extract just the portion of the HTML I'm trying to select then the XPath works just fine. If I go one level up then the XPath doesn't work but it's too much HTML to post here!!

Comment: I don’t expect you to copy-paste the entire HTML. I’m suggesting you take the time to make a small sample of the HTML where you can say, “if it works on this sample, it should work for the real thing”. And show us the work you’ve already done. We, the people trying to help you, should be able to run an example of what isn’t working with the least amount of effort to ourselves… make it easy for us to try your work and see where it’s not what you expect.

Comment: I could post a small amount of HTML but I CAN get the XPath to work for that small sample. In that case I have two options: 1. Post all the HTML from inside the next tag up where the XPath DOESN'T work or 2. Start with the next tag up but cut out some of the HTML to come under SO's code pasting limits. 1 generates too much code and I'm concerned under 2 that I'll cause unintended issues by chopping stuff out. That's why I'd posted the link. I've now solved the underlying issue of getting the text but as that wasn't the subject of the post then I can't post that solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the whole text in a list. You can use indexing to get the specific one.

```
response.css('#event-status').getall()
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking to use XPath for this though.